# Coreutils test suite commands

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make, gnu-coreutils

I want to see the commands that are ran by the coreutils test commands.
For example, assuming that I am running the inode.sh test of ls, I do:

```
 make check TESTS=tests/ls/inode.sh VERBOSE=yes SUBDIRS=.
```

I would like to see exactly which 'ls' commands the test is running. That is to say which ls commands are run by inode.sh. Any idea?

Comment: Are you trying to see the commands run by the `tests/ls/inode.sh` script? Or the commands run by make itself? What do you see when you run that command exactly? You could try adding `SHELL+=-x` to that command line to see more.

Comment: I would like to see the 'ls' commands run by tests. When I run the command above I just see the test result: OK or FAIL.

Comment: The `SHELL+=-x` argument might do that but probably won't. You can look at the script presumably or edit it to add `set -x` to the top. But beyond that if you can't control the execution of the script I'm not sure what else you can do.

Comment: I've just tried, I actually see a giant output, but no the ls commands

Comment: Can you not just look at the script in question directly?

Comment: The problem is that I have to see all the commands for all the tests in coreutils, so I have to find an automatic way to filter them.

Comment: Ah. Can you find the line in the makefile that runs the test scripts you specify?

Comment: I think I've got the problem. Those scritps are full of lines like 'set x $(ls -CHi f slink); shift'.  And this won't print anything on the screen, am I right? I am trying to understand what that command does, but I haven't figure it out yet.

Comment: If you `set -x` in the toplevel script that should apply to the sub-shells and you should see it. That command is running that `ls` command and setting the positional parameters of the main script to `x` plus the command's output (after being globbed and word-split). Then shifting the `x` away.

Comment: What worked? `set -x` in the toplevel script(s)?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
strace -f -e execve -o execs.out \
make check TESTS=tests/ls/inode.sh VERBOSE=yes SUBDIRS=.
grep -F src/ execs.out
```